# Extract Largest Number from list of strings in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I am trying to extract the largest number from a list of strings in python. The string I'm trying to work with looks like this

```
a = ['a', '3', '5', 'c10', 'foo', 'bar', '999']
```

And I'm trying to get back the largest number. So in this case, it would be 999 and I wan't it back as an int.

I can't seem to find a pretty way of doing this, hope you guys can help.

Comment: Do you consider `10` from the string `c10`?

Comment: `print(max(int(i) for i in a if i.isdigit()))` ?

Comment: Are the numbers always positive integers?

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: *"The string I'm trying to work with"* - you mean array?

Comment: a = ['a', '3', '5', 'c1000', 'foo', 'bar', '999'];
mx = max( [int(x) for x in a if x.isnumeric()]) # mx is 999 instead of 1000

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 max( [int(x) for x in a if x.isnumeric()])
```

Comment: This only works if the numbers are always positive integers, which is likely, but OP needs to confirm.

Comment: Youre right, I still assumed it to be sufficient for OPs needs. Otherwise it would of course be more complicated.

Comment: This is sufficient for my case. Thank you